# Java to edit the existing file

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I would like to edit the existing file through Java to have a line break and followed by a space say after each 4th character of the line.So below is the expectation.

```
File Content
------------
abcdef
gh
ijklmn

Expected output
--------------
abcd
 ef
gh
ijkl
 mn
```

Below is the tried code but this writes all in a single line.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReplaceFileContents {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     new ReplaceFileContents().replace();
   }

   public void replace() {
      String oldFileName = "Changed1.ldif";
      String tmpFileName = "Changed2.ldif";

      BufferedReader br = null;
      BufferedWriter bw = null;
      try {
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldFileName));
         bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmpFileName));
         String line;


         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {       
                line=line.replaceAll("(.{4})", "$1\n ");       
                bw.write(line);
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         return;
      } finally {
         try {
            if(br != null)
               br.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            //
         }
         try {
            if(bw != null)
               bw.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            //
         }
      }
      // Once everything is complete, delete old file..
      File oldFile = new File(oldFileName);
      oldFile.delete();

      // And rename tmp file's name to old file name
      File newFile = new File(tmpFileName);
      newFile.renameTo(oldFile);

   }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having with this code ??

Comment: @Sanjeev as per the question `but this writes all in a single line`

Comment: What if you use `"$1" + System.getProperty("line.separator");` instead of `"$1\n"?

Comment: @ScaryWombat My mistake i missed that line somehow. Thanks

Comment: use \n to goes to new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not writing a line separator after each line. You need to add it specifically

```
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {       
            line=line.replaceAll("(.{4})", "$1\n ");       
            bw.write(line);
            bw.newLine();
     }
```

Comment: Agreed. Thanks, that will be system independent.